# Correct sequence of model interpretation

Tags: interaction, assumptions, glmm, ggplot2, lme4-nlme

My question is: what is the right sequence of analyzing? And is it the right way to ggplot errorbars from that model?

**1) Setup model**

I expect possible interactions between treatment, race, age and time, so i start with the full model:

```
dependent variable ~ time * treatment * race * age, random=~subject

time:      7 time points(1min, 2min, ... to 7min)
treatment: treatment and no treatment
race:      race1 and race2
age:       age1 (10 months old) and age2 (20 months old)
subject:   random factor for repeated measures within one subject
```

So far i'm doing it the following way (with R):

I'm interested in the change of dependent variable over time in dependence of age, race, and treatment (all with possible interactions)

so i set up a model:

```
library(nlme)
model <- lme(dv ~ time*treatment*race*age, random=~1|subject, data=mydata, method = "ML")
```

**2) I try to justify the model** (I use either a or b. What is better / enough?)

Is it justified to use a, even though i continue using the lme-function from the library(nlme)? That's why i rather tend to use version b...

**a)**

```
glmmMCMC(dv ~ time * treatment * race * age, random=~subject, data=mydata)
```

pMCMC is < 0.05 for

```
time 
time * treatment
time * treatment * age
time * treatment * age * race (only for some dv = dependent variables)
```

- Does is justify the full model (dv ~ time * treatment * race * age) for all dependent variables, even those who are not significant for the last row of pMCMC-values? Or do i need to setup a new model?

  ```
  model.new <- lme(dv ~ time + time*treatment + time*treatment*age, ...)
  ```

  for those dv, where the last line is not significant
- And do i need to adjust those p-values? Because i got a a lot of them (each fixed effect alone and each combination). Or is it already adjusted or doesn't need to have its p-values adjusted after this

**b)** comparison with reduced models

```
a.null = lme(dv ~ 1, random = ~1|subject, data=mydata, method="ML")
a.1    = lme(dv ~ time, random = ~1|subject, data=mydata, method="ML")
a.2    = lme(dv ~ time * treatment, random = ~1|subject, data=mydata, method="ML")
a.3    = lme(dv ~ time * treatment * race, random = ~1|subject, data=mydata, method="ML")
a.4    = lme(dv ~ time * treatment * race * age, random = ~1|subject, data=mydata, method="ML")
anova(a.null, a.1, a.2, a.3, a.4)
```

- All models excepct a.1 are significant (each compared to the previous model) --> enough justification of the model? Do i need to adjust the p-values from the anova results?

**3) I check for assumptions to use the LMM instead of the GLMM:**

```
hist(scale(residuals(model))) ---> check for normal distribution
qqnorm(scale(residuals(model))) ---> check for normal distribution
plot(fitted(model),residuals(model)) --> check for homoscedasticity
the breadboard does not indicate to collinearity between time, treatment, race, age
```

According to the graphs, there are no obvious violations of the assumptions needed for the linear mixed effect model. (If there are in some cases, i add a weights factor, in order to continue using the linear mixed model instead to switch to the GLMM, because there are some packages i want to use that i can only use with the LMM)

**4) Visualisation**

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mydata, aes(time, dv, color = treatment))
+ stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line")
+ stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom="pointrange")
+ facet_grid(race ~ age)
```

- Is this the right use of error-bars?
- I think not, because the ggplot does not account for repeated measures, and thus the error_bars are way too small... So what would be the correct way of plotting error_bars into this ggplot?

edit:

I have 4 dependent variables dv1, dv2, dv3 and dv4.

The statement in 2)a) "time * treatment * age * race (only for some dv = dependent variables)" could be read as followed:

For some dependent variables i got significant pMCMC-values for time * treatment * age * race, for others not. Am i still allowed to use the full model in those cases?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your overall question, but I might answer some.

You're asking if you need all 4 **independent** variables? You're saying dependent, but if they were dependent your 4 variables would be redundant - just pick the one with the highest desirable effect. If they are independent you can use a Rough Set approach to pick out the variables with the highest desirable effect. I'll explain how if I've understood your question correctly.

Comment: Not quite, i got one dependent variable, and 4 independent variables (time, treatment, race and age). My general question first is if the sequence of model selection is alright (1 to 4) and the more specifical questions are asked in each subgroup. Your question refers to number 2: i'm asking there, if i still can use my full model (time*treatment*race*age), even though in some cases ( i got 3 dependent variables im looking into) the (time*treatment*race*age)-interaction is not significant. And the second question in that group is, if a is preferd to b or i still can use b.